# How to calculate central frequency in LTE Uplink frequency spectrum?

Tags: cellular-network, lte

I want to use scenario C2 in WINNER II channel models. The pathloss formula is as follow:

```
PL = 40log(d) + 13.47 - 14log(hBS) - 14log(hMS) + 6log(fc/5.0)
```

I know all of parameters except `fc`. It shows central frequency of spectrum and because I am using uplink spectrum, I think it should be central frequency in UL. Can any one help me about this parameter?

I didn't find any other forum to ask my question. If I choose wrong one please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fc would be whatever frequency your transmission of interest is. If you are interested in characterizing UL pathloss, you should use whatever frequency the UL transmission is centered at.

However, Table 2.1 of (http://www.cept.org/files/1050/documents/winner2%20-%20final%20report.pdf) mentions the scenario C2 is for 2-6 GHz. Assuming you are interested in LTE, some LTE frequencies aren't in this range. This doesn't mean the model won't give you similar results, but the authors of this model don't claim to model for those frequencies of interest (the ones outside 2-6 GHz)